# INSERT OLD PASSWORD ON A NEW DATABASE

Tags: magento-1.9, php, password

I would like to get the password of the old customers of the old bank and pass to a new bank, I give a getPasswordHash and it brings me an encrypted password, I try to insert it into the bank but when I do a test the password is not the same.

Comment: As magento uses MD5 for password encryption,and it is a one way function. You can not get original text from this.

Comment: Would I need to retrieve the original text to insert it into a new bank? Could not I get the encrypted password and play in the new bank?

Comment: If you have moved your customer into new database , you can send a change password link to them